# How can I structure this SQL query that requires a window function?

Tags: sql, sqlite, partition

I have a group of workers who can take calls or assist with other's calls. That is, all workers either take the call initially ("primary") OR support someone else who has taken the call first ("support"). The database looks like this:

```
| CallAnsweredBy | SupportedBy | Outcome | Date     |
| -------------- | ----------- | ------- | -------- |
| TeamMem1       | TeamMem2    | 10      | 20230101
| TeamMem2       | TeamMem1    | 10      | 20230101
| TeamMem3       | TeamMem1    | 9       | 20230101
. . .
| TeamMem2       | TeamMem1    | 5       | 20230101
| TeamMem3       | TeamMem4    | 4       | 20230101
. . .
```

I want to know that when call #2 (second row above) came in (for example), how many calls over that whole day had the answering person (TM2) supported before taking that call as primary? (For call #2 on 20230101, the answer would be 1. For call #3, the answer would be zero, since TeamMem3 had not supported any calls before that one taken as "primary.")

I've tried PARTITION BY for situations like this before, but that's not helping this time.

Comment: I don't feel like a window function is the appropriate way to solve this one.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the same thing! I've been trying different options with SELF JOIN as the idea but so far nothing. . .

Comment: Too many meetings this afternoon. Something like a correlated subquery `SELECT CallAnsweredBy, (SELECT count(*) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.CalledAnsweredBy = t2.SupportedBy AND t1.date > t2.date) as CallsSupported FROM table t1;` would do the trick. That correlated subquery could be moved into the FROM clause as well, which may give better performance, although that may get tricky with the date restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one with a SELF JOIN. The count of calls supported previously (Supported By) coming from the t2 where the row number was less than the t1 row (as JNevill suggested) was the key.